# Store multiple rows data from dynamic tabular form in php

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, forms, codeigniter

Here, I have a dynamic tabular form where user can add or delete multiple rows.

**Like this:**

[image]

Now whenever I fill two or more rows with data, it transmit only single (first) data of first row via `POST` method.

Now, whenever I have fill data(s) like below.

[image]

its gives me this:

```
Array ( 
    [clientName] => Hello 
    [clientAddress] => 93638524 
        [itemName] => Array([0] => Enduramass) 
        [price]      => Array([0] => 1500) 
        [gst]        => Array([0] => 4) 
        [quantity] => Array([0] => 1) 
        [total]      => Array([0] => 1500) 
    [subTotal]   => 21500.00 
    [totalGstAmount] => 1060.00
    [totalAftertax] => 22560 
)
```

**Here is my html form**

```
<tr>
    <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="itemName[]" id="itemName_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="price[]" id="price_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="gst[]" id="gst_1" class="form-control totalLineGST" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_1" class="form-control changesNo" min="1" max="5" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="total_1" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" readonly><input type="text" id="eachgstAmount_1" class="form-control totalEachGST" ></td>
</tr>
```

**And here is my jQuery multiple append row code**

```
var i=$('table tr').length;
$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
    html = '<tr>';
    html += '<td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="itemName[]" id="itemName_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="price[]" id="price_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off" readonly></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="gst[]" id="gst_'+i+'" class="form-control totalLineGST" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" readonly></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" min="1" max="5" id="quantity_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="total_'+i+'" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" readonly>';
    html += '<input type="text" id="eachgstAmount_'+i+'" class="form-control totalEachGST" >';
    html += '</td></tr>';
    $('table').append(html);
    i++;
});
```

Please guide me, where am I going wrong?

Comment: how do you build your form ?

Comment: post your php code how you fetch your submitted data

Comment: i'm using codeigniter framework. and i just print_r(S_POST); in my controller

Comment: Try with setting an array for checkbox field too. I.e. `<td><input type="checkbox" name="someCheckboxName[]" class="case"/></td>`.